# Unable to retrieve value for key from NSMutableDictionary though it has data

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have code like below :

1.I have below method as action for one button.

```
(IBAction)enableDisableFB:(id)sender {//have below local variable
NSMutableDictionary *fbLocationLatitude = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

2.There is a loop in which i set objects in this dictionary like

```
[fbLocationLatitude setObject:latitude forKey:locID]; //here latitude and locID both are NSString
```

3.In Another loop in same method, I am trying to retrieve value but it gives (null) in NSLog

```
NSLog(@"latitude for key %@ = %@",locID, [fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID]);
//above statement gives me output -> latitude for key 114943251851302 = (null)
```

But right after loop I print complete dictionary using

```
NSLog(@"location dictionary = %@",fbLocationLatitude);
//which gives me below output. Sample given

location dictionary = {
    114943251851302 = "40.4414";
    109782595706984 = "38.9966";
    108867759137051 = "22.47";
    110148382341970 = "25.7877";
    107611279261754 = "43.1655";
    111803735513513 = "27.1828";
    109155699106505 = "18.3167";
    103734539665100 = "19.09";
```

This has the value for key I am searching for but same I am unable to get using objectForKey.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
for (NSUInteger i =0; i< [fbLocationID count];i++)
{
    // NSLog(@"person creation");
    NSString *locID = [NSString stringWithString:[fbLocationID objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"latitude for key %@ = %@",locID, [fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID]);                             
}
NSLog(@"location dictionary = %@",fbLocationLatitude);
```

This is how code is. I also tried to print class of keys using below code

```
for (id ik in [fbLocationLatitude allKeys])
{
const char* classname=class_getName([ik class]);
NSLog(@"class of key %s",classname);
}
```

and I am getting ans as : class of key NSDecimalNumber
Though type casting locID to NSDecimalNumber, I don't get exact value of key but only null.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Are you positive `latitude` isn't `nil` when you're adding values to the dictionary?

Comment: After which loop does the log of the dictionary give you the correct values?  The first one where you add the values, or the second one where you try to retrieve them?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before your NSLog call and inspect the types and the values of of the content of your dictionary in gdb.

Comment: Show the code for how you do the loop to get the values out (what are you looping through)?

Comment: Are you sure the keys are strings?  They don't print with quotes like the values do. Maybe they are NSNumber?

Comment: Your last edit confirms they are NSNumber. I've given a practical answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The keys are NSDecimalNumber, but you are starting with an NSString, so you can extract the data like this:

```
NSDecimalNumber locIDnumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: locID];
id latitude = [fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locIDnumber];
NSLog(@"latitude for key %@ = %@", locID, latitude);
```

You say you tried a cast, but this doesn't perform any conversion from one object type to another; you need a method like `decimalNumberWithString:`

Comment: Perfect I see it's working. Thanks a lot. Sorry I am new here so ccouldn't vote up to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

check like this:

```
if([[fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID] isKindofClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
   NSNumber *num = fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID];
}
else if([[fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID] isKindofClass:[NSString class]])
{
   NSString *strnum = fbLocationLatitude objectForKey:locID];
}
```

Comment: @Adam : Yeah i am sure because same dictionary i NSlog at end and i see all values in it.

Comment: @rdelmer After first loop, if I get values i get them correct, but after second loop, dictionary has value like I given above but objectForKey couldn't retrieve them.

Comment: @sameer : i am taking String locID from array and using that to search this dictionary to get the relevant value...hope i am clear. I have a NSArray where i store all locID values.

Comment: and all --> I updated exact I am using. Prince, it didn't work and nothing was printed in NSLog.